# How to ask people if they are currently going commando

Tags: questions, slang

When asking people if they are currently going commando (not wearing underwear), should I say

> Did you came commando?

or

> Are you on commando?

or something else?

Comment: There are other more important problems in your grammar regardless of whether **someone** is wearing underpants or not.

Comment: @EddieKal Might consider changing "his" to "he". It is less than six characters hence I am unable to do it.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Thanks for spotting the error. I changed it to the gender inclusive "they".

Answer (score 0):

## Don't ask, unless it's your sexual partner, or you're a medical professional.

This would be regarded as *very* rude to ask someone, so just don't. Exceptions might be if the person you were asking was your sexual partner, in which case it *might* be acceptable, depending on context, or if you were a medical professional with a legitimate need to know, in which case you would avoid slang and ask something like "Are you wearing underwear?".

If you *were* going to ask a sexual partner about their underwear, you'd say something like "Are you going commando?" if you were going to use that idiom. "Going commando" is an idiom, and changing the first word is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps! This is meant to be used in a novel, where a man asks this question to his sexual partner. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: "_"Going commando" is an idiom, and changing the first word is incorrect._" Actually people do that all the time. Both versions suggested in the question work. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nct9lbXXD1c). Numerous instances of various versions of this phrase in there. "People work out commando all the time." is one of them.

Comment: Must you use  such large letters?? Also, if the person is a friend, it's FINE. Could be two guys in a gym or lovers or running partners.

Comment: @Lambie I agree. People even [ask such questions on TV](https://youtu.be/pA6EiM5HgBg?t=58).